# Statically partitioning tbb::parallel_for

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb

I have a dataset which I'd like to consume with `tbb::parallel_for` in intervals of size `interval_size`. Each interval that my functor consumes should be `interval_size`, except for the last partial interval, which may be smaller when `interval_size` does not evenly divide my dataset.

Is there a way to use TBB to statically partition in this manner? This test produces several intervals smaller than `interval_size` on my system:

```
#include <tbb/parallel_for.h>
#include <iostream>

struct body
{
  void operator()(const tbb::blocked_range<size_t> &r) const
  {
    std::cout << "range size: " << r.end() - r.begin() << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  size_t num_intervals = 4;
  size_t interval_size = 3;

  // consume num_intervals plus a partial interval in total
  size_t n = num_intervals * interval_size + (interval_size - 1);
  tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<size_t>(0, n, interval_size),
                    body(),
                    tbb::simple_partitioner());

  return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
$ g++ test_parallel_for.cpp -ltbb
$ ./a.out 
range size: 3
range size: 2
range size: 2
range size: 3
range size: 2
range size: 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the behaviour is that the simple partitioner partitions your range by the following criteria:

> ceil(grainsize/2) <= chunksize <= grainsize

when used with `tbb::blocked_range(i, j, grainsize)` and chunksize is the size of your range.

You can check the [Tutorial](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/uploads/81/91/Latest%20Open%20Source%20Documentation/Tutorial.pdf) for more information under *3.2.5 Partitioner Summary*.

There is no easy way to get a fixed size chunksize with TBB (you can easily achieve this with OpenMP). That is because this is against the concepts of TBB. TBB tries to abstract all those stuff away from you and the scheduler makes sure that your threads are used the best as possible on runtime.

Comment: Thanks. Does TBB provide a guarantee that the chunksize will never exceed the `grainsize` provided with `blocked_range`?

Comment: @JaredHoberock If you use the `simple_partitioner` the equation above is guaranteed.